Normalizing EEG data in EEGlab through code
I want to ask what function or what sort of normalization is behind the the 'norm' button on EEGlab? I want to automate this process as I have many files to inspect visually. I tried zscore normalization with default parameters but the results are not same as the normalization through 'norm' button. I have attached the image of the GUI which I am referring to.


better to check on their website

Cannot find there. Can you help me find it please

From the EEGLab github, searching for norm you can see the button definition:
https://github.com/sccn/eeglab/blob/65440a57cfe7e3ebe22e292aa0279e9c72b6efce/functions/sigprocfunc/eegplot.m#L79
%    "Norm/Denorm" - [button] "Norm" normalizes each channel separately such that all
%                  channels have the same standard deviation without changing original 
%                  data/activations under EEG structure. "Denorm" undoes the operation.  

The actual code which does the normalisation looks a little funky because it's a char as the callback to the Norm button function, but will a little effort you can pull out the actual functionality if you need to
  cb_normalize = ['g = get(gcbf,''userdata'');if g.normed, disp(''Denormalizing...''); else, disp(''Normalizing...''); end;'...
    'hmenu = findobj(gcf, ''Tag'', ''Normalize_menu'');' ...
    'ax1 = findobj(''tag'',''eegaxis'',''parent'',gcbf);' ...
    'data = get(ax1,''UserData'');' ...
    'if isempty(g.datastd), g.datastd = std(data(:,1:min(1000,g.frames),[],2)); end;'...
    'if g.normed, '...
    'for i = 1:size(data,1), '...
    'data(i,:,:) = data(i,:,:)*g.datastd(i);'...
    'if ~isempty(g.data2), g.data2(i,:,:) = g.data2(i,:,:)*g.datastd(i);end;'...
    'end;'...
    'set(gcbo,''string'', ''Norm'');set(findobj(''tag'',''ESpacing'',''parent'',gcbf),''string'',num2str(g.oldspacing));' ...
    'else, for i = 1:size(data,1),'...
    'data(i,:,:) = data(i,:,:)/g.datastd(i);'...
    'if ~isempty(g.data2), g.data2(i,:,:) = g.data2(i,:,:)/g.datastd(i);end;'...
    'end;'...
    'set(gcbo,''string'', ''Denorm'');g.oldspacing = g.spacing;set(findobj(''tag'',''ESpacing'',''parent'',gcbf),''string'',''5'');end;' ...
    'g.normed = 1 - g.normed;' ...
    'eegplot(''draws'',0);'...
    'set(hmenu, ''Label'', fastif(g.normed,''Denormalize channels'',''Normalize channels''));' ...
    'set(gcbf,''userdata'',g);set(ax1,''UserData'',data);clear ax1 g data;' ...
    'eegplot(''drawp'',0);' ...
    'disp(''Done.'')'];


Thanks, @wolfie, it was helpful as I found in this function that if the data is not normalized (g.normed is false), it normalizes the data by dividing each data point by its corresponding standard deviation.
